# Ansible lookup for particular key

Tags: azure, ansible

I have to check the target vm's /etc/hosts file. If any ips which starts with 10.*.*.* Are there in that file.it should report yes and show the ips and if there is no ips .it should report No under that target hostname . All this information should come to build artifacts in azure pipelines.. please suggest me that possibilities

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried lookup.. it's giving complete file data with  /n /n in between..

Comment: I have tried shell module to cat the content and register the output but stuck there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `file` lookup was actually a pretty good start. But as all [lookups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html), it only runs on the controller machine (localhost). If you need to run this on a remote target vm, you will have to read the file from there. The idea I followed below is:

- Use the [`slurp` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) to get `/etc/hosts` content from the target in a variable on the controller
- split the content of the file on the new line character to get a list of lines.
- loop on those lines and add the matching ips to a list. The ips are searched using a regexp with the [`match` test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) and the [`regex_search` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters)
- show the content of the resulting list if that list is not empty.

The example playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Check ips starting with 10. in /etc/hosts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Slurp /etc/hosts content from target vm
      slurp:
        src: /etc/hosts
      register: my_host_entries_slurped

    - name: Read /etc/hosts file in a list line by line
      set_fact:
        my_host_entries: "{{ (my_host_entries_slurped.content | b64decode).split('\n') }}"

    - name: Add matching ips to a list
      vars:
        ip_regex: "^10(\\.\\d{1,3}){3}"
      set_fact:
        matching_ips: "{{ matching_ips | default([]) + [item | regex_search(ip_regex)] }}"
      when: item is match(ip_regex)
      loop: "{{ my_host_entries }}"

    - name: Show list of matching ips
      debug:
        var: matching_ips
      when: matching_ips | default([]) | length > 0
```

You can adapt to match your exact needs.

Note: if you are not totally familiar with regexp, the one I used which is (without the escaped `\\` in the yaml string)

```
^10(\.\d{1,3}){3}
```

means:
search for `10` at the beginning of the line folowed by a group of chars starting with a `.` and followed by 1 to 3 digits. Repeat this last group 3 times exactly.

Comment: This is listing ips but thos ips are not there in /etc/host. I dont know from where its showing.. Is there any way to list  last 5 lines from the file and save it in txt or csv file

Comment: Oups ! My bad ! Lookups only work on controller machine. Updated to use the slurp module and effectively fetch the file from the target.

Comment: your script worked wonderfully. THankyou . Am looking to move all the target machine IPs, which have matching_ips to a excel sheet. Could you suggest for any possibilities

Comment: Or just matching_ips to get in text file

Comment: if this fixes your issue you should accept the answer so other users know there is a working solution. Now you have the list of ips in a list, you can easily create a template to write the output to a csv flie. Try to do something on your own and come back here to ask an other question if you have problems.